# How to use unset with xargs in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I want to write bash script, to remove some environmental variable

my problem is when I run below command

```bash
env | grep -i _proxy= | cut -d "=" -f1 | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

I see below result

```
HTTPS_PROXY
HTTP_PROXY
ALL_PROXY
```

but when I replace `echo` with `unset`, something like below

```bash
env | grep -i _proxy= | cut -d "=" -f1 | xargs -I {} unset {}
```

I see below error

```
xargs: unset: No such file or directory
```

What is my problem? If I use `xargs` incorrectly?

Comment: Duplicate of [Unset all ENV variables matching _PROXY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209895/unset-all-env-variables-matching-proxy)

Comment: `unset` can only change the shell that runs it (and moreover, it's a shell builtin, a _part of the shell_, not an external command). `xargs` isn't a shell builtin, so both it itself and anything it runs is a separate process from that shell (meaning it can't run shell builtins at all unless it starts a shell to run them... and if it does that, the new shell is a different shell from the one that started xargs, and can't modify that original/parent shell's state).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have xargs running in a pipeline. Therefore it is running in a separate process, and it cannot alter the environment of the "parent" shell.

Also, xargs works with commands, not shell builtins.

You'll need to do this:

```sh
while read -r varname; do unset "$varname"; done < <(
    env | grep -i _proxy= | cut -d "=" -f1
)
```

or

```sh
mapfile -t varnames  < <(env | grep -i _proxy= | cut -d "=" -f1)
unset "${varnames[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this:

```
]$ env |grep AWS_|tr "=" " "|awk '{print $1}'
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
]$ env |grep AWS_|tr "=" " "|awk '{print $1}'|xargs -n1 unset
xargs: unset: No such file or directory
]$
```

And below simple solution worked for me

```
unset `env |grep AWS_|tr "=" " "|awk '{print $1}'`
```

or below

```
unset `env |grep AWS_|cut -d= -f1`
```